# Microsoft Azure - Assigning Microsoft Graph permissions to a regular user doesn't work

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api

I understand the process of assigning Microsoft Graph permissions to a service principal. I can take the object id of the Microsoft Graph app, then use the `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals/<id>/appRoleAssignedTo` MSGraph endpoint, like described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-grant-via-msgraph?tabs=http&pivots=grant-application-permissions).

My question is: can I do the same with a regular user? That is, when calling `appRoleAssignedTo`, specify the object id of a user in the `principalId` field. Can a regular user have application permissions (like MSGraph permissions), and how do I use them afterwards?

I tried to do the above and assign the `RoleManagement.ReadWrite.Directory` to a user. Then I logged in with `az login` and ran `az account get-access-token --resource-type ms-graph`.

With this token I tried to do an operation that requires the `RoleManagement.ReadWrite.Directory` permission, like assigning a role to another user, but it fails with `Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.`.

Answer (score 0):

Users can request the scope they need when using `Connect-MgGraph`, for example:

```
Connect-MgGraph -Scopes "RoleManagement.ReadWrite.Directory"
```

Which is the recommended approach, as it means that for that session they will only have access to the scopes that are necessary rather than any they've previously requested

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the same error as below:***

[image]

> **Note** that: Microsoft Graph API permissions can be assigned only to Service principals not users directly.

When I tried to `Connect-MgGraph` as a normal user, I got the error like below:

```
Connect-MgGraph -Scopes "RoleManagement.ReadWrite.Directory"
```

[image]

[image]

I created an **Azure AD Application and granted API permission** as below:

[image]

I generated **access token** by using below parameters:

```json
GET https://login.microsoftonline.com/1810a95e-99f3-46e0-84e8-8a2aee05d830/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
client_secret:*****
scope:RoleManagement.ReadWrite.Directory
grant_type:authorization_code
redirect_uri:RedirectUri
code:code
```

[image]

By using the above access token, I am able to assign directory role to the user successfully as below:

```json
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryRoles/roleTemplateId=88d8e3e3-8f55-4a1e-953a-9b9898b8876b/members/$ref
Content-type: application/json

{
  "@odata.id": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryObjects/UserID"
}
```

[image]

**Reference:**

[Add graph api permission to user account by Harpreet Singh Matharoo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1024932/add-graph-api-permission-to-user-account-(service))

Comment: From your screenshots it's impossible to read which endpoints do you call

Comment: > Note that: Microsoft Graph API permissions can be assigned only to Service principals not users directly.


This is exactly what my question is about. Is this behavior documented? Because the api allows you to assign graph permissions to a user, but I can't figure out how to use them afterwards.

Comment: AFAIK there is no documentation for the same.

Comment: You should generate the access token for the Service Principal and log in as a user while generating the access token. Or else assign the user to the Application and check..